# assembly language find the number

Tags: assembly

I have to do a project in assembly language and i am really stacked.I want to generate a random number(0-9)after that i choose and number until i find the number. 
I dont need something so complicated please

```
    .MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA

m1 DB 'The number is bigger ','$'
m2 DB 'The number is smaller','$'
m3 DB 'You won','$'
m4 DB 'Choose the number ','$'
.CODE
MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS,AX
MOV AH,09H
MOV DX,OFFSET m4
INT 21H
RANDGEN:      
RANDSTART:
   MOV AH, 00h 
   INT 1AH          

   MOV BH, 57  
   MOV AH, DL  
   CMP AH, BH    
   JA RANDSTART 

   MOV BH, 49   
   MOV AH, DL   
   CMP AH, BH   
   JB RANDSTART 


   mov ah, 2h  
   int 21h     
E1:MOV AH,01H
INT 21H
CMP AL,DL
JG E2
CMP AL,DL
JL E3
MOV AH,09H
MOV DX,OFFSET m3
INT 21H
JMP E4

E2:MOV AH,09H
MOV DX,OFFSET m1
JMP E1

E3:MOV AH,09H
MOV DX,OFFSET m2
JMP E1

E4:MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
END
```

Comment: what architecture is this? Explain more detailed what this does and what you expect it to do.

Comment: I want to generate a random number and then choose numbers until I will find that number.But when I choose a number my program always shows "your number is smaller"

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely **essential you learn how to use some debugger** and watch yourself what your code does.

Until you find some debugger and learn how to use it, **stop programming in Assembly**, there's no point to continue, you will just waste your time, and even others, if you will bring every trivial problem to stack overflow or some other forum.

You should use those "Internet" thing only when you are "stuck" by not understanding particular thing. Which means you can well describe what is the CPU state ahead of some short code, what it is after executing it, what did you expect and why/how does it differ from your expectations. Then people can explain you why your expectations are wrong.

But if you will use also instruction reference guide to verify your expectations about particular instructions, you will be able to fix 90% of these bugs on your own in very short time.

---

Some things you should learn (and re-read your source with fresh eyes to apply these to find bugs in your code).

1. CPU register are "super globals", whoever wrote last value into register, that value is in it. If you want to preserve some value for some time, either make sure that register is not change by next part of code, or store the value somewhere in [stack] memory. Or copy (`mov`) it to some register, which is not used in next part of code, if you need the one where the value is at the moment.
2. `DL`, `DH` and `DX` are all the same register of CPU, just different parts (groups of bits) of it. `DX` = `DH`*256 + `DL`, or when you view it as binary numbers, then `DL` is lower 8 bits of `DX`, and `DH` is upper 8 bits. `DX` is of course 8+8 = 16 bits. Third bit in `DH` is thus also eleventh bit of `DX` at the same time, it's physically the same bit.
3. flags are also just a numeric value in register (`F`), which is affected only by some instructions. If you will read instruction reference guide about `Jcc` (jump by condition code) instructions family, you will learn those do NOT affect value of `F` (flags), so in this case:

   ```
   CMP AL,DL
   JG E2
   CMP AL,DL
   JL E3
   ```

   That second `CMP` will do nothing new, already the first did set flags. And value in register is there, until it is changed by some instruction, it will not evaporate "just so". By using redundant instructions in such super short piece of code you are showing either lack of understanding, or wasteful approach (redundant instructions do waste cycles of CPU, which was very costly thing to do back in 1980s and in trivial cases like this one it would earn you LOT of frowns and mockery ... like I'm doing here (the frown part for sure, not sure about mockery, it's hard to be asshole nowadays as people go ask for advice already at this stage of skill normally, back in 1980s this would be like asking to be publicly ashamed for not grasping at least basics on your own, but now it's supposed to be OK)).
4. finally about your random generator:

   ```
       INT 1AH

       MOV BH, 57  
       MOV AH, DL  
       CMP AH, BH    
       JA RANDSTART 

       MOV BH, 49   
       MOV AH, DL   
       CMP AH, BH   
       JB RANDSTART
   ```

   This is again wasting many CPU cycles, and wasting several source lines, and overall it is being unreasonably cryptic, so the source is not easy to read and follow. Consider this alternative way of the same thing:

   ```
       INT 1AH
       ; cx:dx is 32 bit clock "time" in (1/18.21)s since boot
       ; I will use the least significant 8 bits of it (DL) as random ASCII digit

       CMP DL, '9'  
       JA RANDSTART 
       CMP DL, '0'   ; your original code compares with '1'!
       JB RANDSTART 
       ; so your original code will produce only 1-9 ASCII digits
   ```

   That's the same thing (plus fix to return 0-9 instead of 1-9 digits). Notice how now the source "tells" you the story *"compare with ASCII digit `'9'`, when above, do new random. Then compare with ASCII digit `'0'`, when below, do new random."*, any seasoned x86 ASM programmer will read that almost fluently and immediately understand.
5. and one more thing about that "random" generator. `DL` is 8 bits register, so it can have value from 0 to 2<sup>8</sup>-1 (when you present those 8 bits as unsigned integer). But you will go further only when `'0' <= DL <= '9'`, that's 10 "legal" values of `DL`. If the clock returns ASCII character `':'` (`58` in decimal), it will take approximately 14 seconds, until the `DL` will go through all the `58-255` and then `0-47` values. That's sort of very slow random generator (also not very random).

   To somewhat improve it by naive way, you can do this for example:

   ```
       INT 1AH
       ; cx:dx is 32 bit clock "time" in (1/18.21)s since boot

       AND   DL,15      ; keep only bottom 4 bits (0-15) value in DL
                        ; (cheaply, AND is very fast bitwise operation)
       CMP   DL,9       ; it's 9 this time, not '9' (57).
       JA    RANDSTART  ; values 10-15 will restart random
          ; will keep restarting for 6/18.21 = ~0.33 of second
          ; at most, puny human can wait that short while

       ; remaining legal values 0-9 will be converted to ASCII digit
       ADD   DL,'0'
       ; here DL is some "random" value from '0' to '9'
       ; unfortunately the value '0' will be somewhat preferred over others
   ```

If you will fully understand these, and re-read your source, you should be able to find all your bugs. Or even better, use the debugger to see by your own eyes, what each instruction does, and what happens to the CPU state after each of them.

Also if you will understand these, your next source will be more readable, shorter and easier to decipher, both for you and for other readers. When you present your current code to some experienced ASM programmer, they will keep saying *"everybody has to learn it somehow, it's OK for a start"*, but the other part of mind will also yell *"kill it, kill it before it lays eggs."* By doing some basic refactoring, removing the basic waste from your source like duplicities/etc and using proper constants or `Jcc` aliases following semantics: you will do your questions easier to read and to answer (plus the answer will be very likely to the point only, omitting lot of useless babbling).

As your code doesn't use any memory storage, it should be very easy to follow the important parts of CPU state, just by looking at register view and following values in registers which are important for you in particular part of code (tracing values in larger memory blocks is a bit more tedious, but of course doable, if such need would arise, debugger allows you also to view memory content).

And in case I didn't mention it already, it's absolutely essential you learn to use some debugger.